# Why does using float instead of int gives me different results when all of my inputs are integers?

Tags: c

```
void main( )
{
    int no = 123;
    while(no)
    { 
        no /= 10;
        printf("%d", no % 10);
    }
}
```

Results:

- 2
- 210
- 21
- 213

Why does using float instead of int gives me different results when all of my inputs are integers?

Comment: Using `float` *how*?  If you're asking about the difference in behavior between two programs, then present both programs.

Comment: What inputs? This code doesn't even take any inputs.

Comment: First you have to take the remainder, then perform the division, so you should swap `no/=10;` and `printf("%d", no%10);`

Comment: You cannot just give people a list of items, not say what they are, and expect people to understand it. Nobody knows what “1. 2 2. 210 3. 21 4. 213” is. Is it a list of inputs? Of outputs? Of intermediate values as the program goes through a sequence of steps? When you are telling people about programs and their behavior, tell them: I have this program (show the code—**all** of it), I give it this input (show the input), and it gives me this output (show the output), but I expect this output (show the expected output). If you are comparing two programs show both, and the different output.

Comment: MORE INFORMATION IS NEEDED! its kinda hard to figure out what you need help with if we don't understand the full problem

Answer (score 0):

If you change `int no` to `float no`, you must also change the `printf` format to `%f` or the behavior would be undefined. Furthermore the `%` operator is not defined for `float` arguments, so what code did you actually try to get your observation?

The reason you get different output is you perform a different computation: division behaves differently for integers and floating point numbers, **except** when the numerator is a multiple of the denominator.